# Retrieve sub-fieldls in firestore to display in flatlist - react native

Tags: react-native, redux, google-cloud-firestore, reducers

Im trying to implement redux that contains the steps of the task and then, display these steps to the screen in a flatlist.
I have created a reducer that contains task data (category, taskname, steps {step1,step2,step3,step4} ..). step1,2,3 and 4 are sub-fields of steps in my firestore db

I pass from screen 1 to screen 2 the id of the task and then I want to display the steps. But when Im writing {item.steps} I get this error : **Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {step1, step2, step3, step4}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

```
   renderItem=(item,index)=>{    
        return(  
        <View style={styles.listItemContainer}>
    
          </View>
        <View style={styles.listItemTitleContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.listItemTitle}>{item.steps}</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
```

Does I have to create a reducer, specifically for the steps?

Comment: `item.steps` is an object. You can have separate `<Text>` for each step and assign `<Text>{item.steps.step1}</Text>` and so on.